# svn:ignore is locally to a computer?

Tags: svn, version-control

When i exclude files from SVN with `svn:ignore` and then another person try to commit the files excluded, **svn** block him? or he have to do the same command in his computer?

Comment: if you commit the folder where the property is set then when the other person svn updates the files will be ignored in his WC as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When i exclude files from SVN with svn:ignore and then another person try to commit the files excluded, svn block him?

No, svn:ignore just define pattern(s) of files, which, if **untracked and exist** inside WC, will be filtered from  output of `svn status` `svn add *`

> he have to do the same command in his computer?

svn:ignore is **versioned property of folder**, stored, with other versioned data, **in repository**. If you commit this data and other side update own WC to this (or later) revision, folder in it's WC will have the same svn:ignore property settings

Answer (score 5):

Imagine if you have a bunch of Java files (`*.java`). These get compiled into `*.class` files. The compiled `*.class` files should not be stored in Subversion.

Now, imagine a developer who created a bunch of new `*.java` files, compiled them, was happy with the results, and did this:

```
$ svn add *
```

In this case, Subversion will merrily add in all the compiled `*.class` files. Not what you want...

The `svn:ignore` property goes on the directory where you want to ignore files. If, and only if a file is not already in Subversion, the file won't show up if the file matches the `svn:ignore` glob pattern on the file, and the user does a `svn status` or an `svn add` with wild cards.

With the `svn status` command, these files won't show up with a `?` mark at the beginning of the lines of output. If a user attempts to add with a wildcard, Subversion will ignore these files.

In the above scenario, if a developer did this:

```
$ svn add *
```

The `svn:ignore` property will prevent the `*.class` files from being added.

However, if a user specifically adds an ignored file:

$ svn add foo.class

Then, Subversion won't ignore the file. And, once it is added to the repository, Subversion will report on it if the file is changed or deleted.

The `svn:ignore` property is visible to all users who have checked out that version of the directory. It's a great way to prevent accidental additions of files, but it can't prevent someone from actually adding them.

I have a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that can take things a step further. With it, you can prevent users from adding specific files into the repository. You can also force users to set a `svn:ignore` when they create a new directory.

Answer (score 1):

The ignore property does not stop anybody from adding files. It only prevents subversion from listing files that match the patters from being listed as "unknown" when doing things like "svn status".

However, it must be committed to the archive in order to be seen by all users.